# MVC3 Razor version of calendar extender

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, calendarextender

I am used to using the textbox calendar extender (which I love!).  However, my newest project is in MVC3 razor and it seems that using AJAX can't be done or at least not in the asp.net way.  What is an alternative to using the calendar extender for AJAX?  Can I still use it using a work around?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery datepicker.

```
    $("#myTextBox").datepicker(
            {
                showOn: 'button',
                dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy",
                buttonImageOnly: true,
                buttonImage: '../../../images/cal.gif',
                constrainInput: false
            });
```

Comment: Does anything need to be added to 
    <input type="text" name="myTextBox" />
Also, is there a specific cal.gif that is needed?

Comment: No specific gif needed, nothing special to do to the text box.  Probably need the code I specified in a document.ready function.  If you googld jQuery datepicker, you will find documentation, examples and there are lots of options.